# Wrong User Directory for Administrator

Tags: active-directory, windows-domain, windows-server

I've been struggling with AD DS on Windows Server 2K8R2 but I finally decided to remove it temporarily. However after the uninstall, the directory which contains Downloads, Music, Desktop, etc. is now "temp" instead of "Administrator".

I can't figure out how to reset this back to default. I'm attempting to reinstall AD DS but I can't proceed until this issue is fixed.

Comment: Try logging into the local user ( or creating one ) instead of the domain user.

Comment: That's what I can't figure out how to do. I'm really new to active directory. Basically I log in using Remote Desktop Connection but no matter what I do, a domain is set. I don't even have active directory turned on and it still boots into the TEMP user folder. I thought if I deleted Administrator.ENTERPRISE, it would default back to the Administrator folder but now it just creates a TEMP directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced this problem as well. When Active Directory is removed, it actually removes the first user "Administrator". All of your settings should still remain in-tact, but the actual user itself gets removed in the uninstall process.

Comment: Thanks! I just did dcpromo.exe and found out this was a warning that the wizard gives out.